# AWS IAM user login failed but root credentials work

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, credentials, amazon-iam

[error message displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMHVF.png)

Created a new IAM user, created a policy and attached it to the user. Everything seems kosher but I'm getting this error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I was using a VPN and that was giving the error. If I logged in from an unmasked IP then I was OK.

Comment: I would post an answer but I cannot post answers due to poor quality answers in the past

Answer (score 0):

Check the IAM sign-in URL used by the user. I have seen this error when there is a typo in the sign in URL:

```
https://<your-account-number-or-nick-name>.signin.aws.amazon.com/console
```

Comment: when I type in the URL it redirects to https://us-east-1.signin.aws.amazon.com/oauth?SignatureVersion=4&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJMOATPLHVSJ563XQ&X-Amz-Date=2018-01-09T20%3A23%3A52.771Z&X-Amz-Signature=0ff6c306e2c85674338cf9456e1593005ced553983c021f7d0e76e83764b43a7&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&client_id=arn%3Aaws%3Aiam%3A%3A015428540659%3Auser%2Fhomepage&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole.aws.amazon.com%2Fconsole%2Fhome%3Fstate%3DhashArgs%2523%26isauthcode%3Dtrue&response_type=code&state=hashArgs%23

Comment: seems like it could be a cookies issue. I've cleared all browsing data from all time and still same issue. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=115572